# Intervals and Distances: Question about a solution

Tags: solution-verification, puzzle

The text of a puzzle could be found in [1].
I have a question concerning the solution of Peter Winkler (that is the same as in the origin in Russian). He claims that if **a** and **b** are two (disjoint) intervals and **I** is interval of distances obtainable by
taking one point from  **a** and one from **b** then **I** has length equal to the sum of lengths of **a** and **b**. But it seems to be wrong because it does not depend from positions of the **a** and **b**.
For example, if the left bound of **a** is 0 and the right bound of **b** is 1 that distance between these points is 1.
So I need explanation of the proof of Winkler or may be some other proof.
[1]: [Peter Winkler's Mathematical Puzzle "Intervals and Distances"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3605413/peter-winklers-mathematical-puzzle-intervals-and-distances/4176550#4176550)

Comment: Remember that we're looking for the interval of possible distances, not just a given distance. So translating either interval will just result in translating that interval of distances, which wouldn't affect the length.

Comment: Ok, while trying to answer to you I understood my mistake: we should get the length of the interval of distances but not values  that are found in this interval. Thank you!